# How to programmatically get a list of my LinkShare merchants from LinkShare?

Tags: api, affiliate

How can I programatically get a list of merchants who have data I am qualified to access via my LinkShare account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following URL will allow you to get a list of merchants with data that you have permission to access without the need to login. It will return an XML list of your merchants:

http://findadvertisers.linksynergy.com/merchantsearch?token=YOUR_LINKSHARE_ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: where on their site did you find this API endpoint? I can't seem to find this in thier docs. It works but if you could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly I did not find it in their docs only on a 3rd-party site's blog, which is why I posted the question and answer on Stack Overflow in case anyone else needed to know about it.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the domain of each of these merchants ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160456/how-to-programmatically-get-a-list-of-my-linkshare-merchants-domains

Comment: is there a way I can get all products of these each merchant?